# How can I implement different realms with form based login on a web site?

Tags: html, http, authentication, passwords, basic-authentication

On the same site, e.g. `www.whatever.com`, I have different logins, e.g. on `/foo/` and `/bar/`. When I use HTTP Basic Auth, logins can have different realms, so that the client (web browser) can distinguish the logins, even if the username is the same. This is nice, because the user can store passwords in the browser for the different realms on the same site. However, for different reasons, I have to use form based logins with a session cookie instead of Basic Auth. How can I have different realms then? Or any other means, so that the web browser can store the different logins correctly?

Comment: When setting the cookie, limit its path, or simply include the "realm" information into the cookie value itself and let the backend handle it.

Comment: @deceze IMHO this would not solve the problem, that the web browser is not able to distinguish the two logins when saving the password. If I'm user "abc" at `/foo/` and also user "abc" at `/bar/`, but with different passwords, the browser would ask to update the password all the time, right?

Comment: The browser doesn't ask anything. Cookie-based logins are entirely implemented by you, there's no default logic the browser applies. It just stores cookies and sends them back to your server, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @deceze But the browser can store username/password. This does not work in my case when using form based login, because the browser does not distinguish the different logins. This works with Basic Auth thanks to the realm. My question was: Is there an equivalent for form based login?